# Are C++ exceptions expected to be handled in main()?

Tags: c++, oop, exception

I am doing a project in C++, and I am new to OOP.

I have some doubts regarding C++ exceptions and where they have to be handled.
I read that it is a good practice to insert the `try/catch` block into the `main()` function, letting the exceptions thrown into "deep placed" methods to climb up to `main()` and be handled there, programming the user feedback in such cases.

The problem is that not all the errors of the project are treated like exceptions, and for that reason high level functions called in `main()` return a bool value that is a first indicator of an error state.

So, I am wondering whether it is a good thing not to handle exceptions in `main()` in that case, placing the `try/catch` block into low-level methods and returning a `false` value in the high-level one when an exception has been caught in the former, allowing me to treat all the errors the same way.

Comment: catch errors where you can recover from them, or do something meaningful. Sometimes even not catching an excpetion but terminating is the right thing to do

Comment: Only catch exceptions if the program can recover from them.  You might want to catch exceptions in `main` (and thread-procs) for the purposes of logging and then re-throw them (`throw;`).

Comment: An exception means that your program is in an undefined state; an event happened that you didn't plan for (otherwise it's not an exception).  Continuing to run the program in an undefined state is a bad idea.

Comment: The project i'm working to is a sort of database that is expected to answer to only one command and then close, saving modified data in a .bin file. For that reason, continuing to run the program would only have the purpose to redirect the error to a function that can formally express it to the user

Comment: @alex So catch in `main`, log to the user and re-throw.

Comment: @RichardCritten: You're quite wrong with your description of exceptions. The word "undefined state" is just the start. See for instance Herb Sutter's articles on weak and strong exception safety. The difference is whether you accept _unspecified_ state. And the reason that constructors have no return values is because errors are returned as exceptions - a failed constructor can certainly be a planned event.

Comment: Exceptions are like an *invisible go to*.  For **exceptional** situations.  Not for *flow control* or *common scenarios*.  Handle them where it makes sense, otherwise allow them to terminate the program.  And keep in mind:  [Bugs Aren't Recoverable Errors!](http://joeduffyblog.com/2016/02/07/the-error-model/#bugs-arent-recoverable-errors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general rule where these handlers should go.

But you describe your program as "high level functions called in `main()` return a bool value". That is a reasonable choice: any specific exception handling is taken care of by those high-level functions. From the perspective of `main`, these high-level functions either succeed or they fail. Hence, `main` does not need to bother with exceptions *in your specific design*.